# ObservableCollection with for next loop

Tags: c#

I have a problem with following C# code.

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var test = new ObservableCollection<Test>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1048576; i++)
        {
            var obj = new Test()
            {
                firname = (string)i["firname"],
                surname = (string)i["surname"]
            };
            test.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Test> test;

    public class Test
    {
        public string firname { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Error picture is here: https://prnt.sc/px0wv0

So how can I solve that two errors?

Comment: Please add the error details to your post, not just the picture's. What have you tried to find out what the issue is? Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through? If not, I would recommend it, it will break on the lines that are causing this issue.

Comment: i is an int and you're using as an array, cannot work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firname = (string)i["firname"],
surname = (string)i["surname"]
```

Makes no sense. You are trying to treat a Int, as if it was a `Dictionar<String, [unknown]>`? And then you try to cast that unknown type to string.

This is the only syntax that make sense, with the given class Test:

```
firname = "firname",
surname = "surname"
```

Or maybe this, if you want slightly different values for the name each itteration, wich can help with learning the mechanics:

```
 firname = i.ToString() + "firname",
 surname = i.ToString() + "surname"
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton Trying to treat a int - the running variable of a for loop - like a String Indexed Collecetion makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The mistakes in that line were just to many to count. Wich is why I simply wrote some code that kinda made sense.